# Is there a way to overflow a markdown table using HTML?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have a blog built using jekyll in GitHub pages. One of my posts (wrote in markdown) have a table, that overflows in smartphones, generating a horizontal scrollbar of entire page.

I want to know if there is some way to write HTML + markdown like bellow, to overflow only the div, not the entire page.

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;">

    |                        |ODBC | SSMS | SQLCMD | ISQL|
    |---                     |:---:|:---: |:---:   |:---:|
    |ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON       | ON  | ON   | ON     | OFF |
    |ANSI_NULLS              | ON  | ON   | ON     | OFF |

</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a repository url, please ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't simply add a html wrapper but you have several other options.

If you are using the Kramdown Markdown engine, just add a wrapper using the following snippet (note the empty line between the `div` tags and the markdown block. This is required.):

```
<div class="table-wrapper" markdown="block">

|                        |ODBC | SSMS | SQLCMD | ISQL|
|---                     |:---:|:---: |:---:   |:---:|
|ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON       | ON  | ON   | ON     | OFF |
|ANSI_NULLS              | ON  | ON   | ON     | OFF |

</div>
```

You can then add the css rule to your sass/css files and set overflow hidden here.

```
.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This is a clear way to set overflow only for selected tables.

Comment: The overflow must be in the div. In table doesn't work.

Comment: Don't forget those empty lines! I forgot and paid the price.